# Pandas read_sql_query with dtype specified converts NULL string column in DB to the string 'None' instead of None

Tags: python, pandas, null

I have a string DB column of the following format:

```
COLUMN_A
NULL
NULL
NULL
STRING_VALUE1
STRING_VALUE2
NULL
...
```

When I query using:

```
pd.read_sql_query('SELECT COLUMN_A FROM TABLE', con=conn, dtype={'COLUMN_A':str})
```

I get a dataframe of the format:

```
COLUMN_A
'None'
'None'
'None'
'STRING_VALUE1'
'STRING_VALUE2'
'None'
```

emphasis on that the `None` values in the df are actually **string** representations of `None` e.g. `'None'` and not the `None` value.

Is this a bug or am I not using `read_sql_query` correctly? I think I would expect a null value in the db to be mapped to the value `None` and not the str value `'None'`. Or is this an issue with `sqlalchemy`?

I am using:

```
sqlalchemy=1.4.44
pyodbc=4.0.35
pandas=1.5.2
Microsoft SQL Server
```

Answer (score 0):

A workaround, or fix to this issue is to use the (currently experimental) string extension type in pandas e.g.

```
pd.read_sql_query('SELECT COLUMN_A FROM TABLE', 
                  con=conn,
                  dtype={'COLUMN_A': pd.StringDtype()})
```

This will return the null values as `pd.NA`